# How to update through model in django many to many?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
class Blog():
  likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="myapp.Like")

class Like():
  user = models.ForeignKey(Like)
  blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
  liked_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  some_bool_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now in views:

```
 def like_blog(request, id):
     blog = Blog.objects.get(id=id)
     blog.users.add(request.user)
     # now how can I update some_bool_field and How can I make use of this field
```

In future I can use some query like `blog.users.filter(some_bool_field=False)` so for that case I want to update this field.

OR AM I MISSING THE USES OF THROUGH MODEL ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the through model objects you can do like so:

```
def like_blog(request, id):
     blog = Blog.objects.get(id=id)
     blog.users.add(request.user)
     # query your through model
     Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, blog=blog).update(some_bool_field=True)
```

Getting all blogs filtered likes with `some_bool_field=True`:

```
true_boolean_likes = Blog.objects.filter(likes__some_bool_field=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

for through model update you can use bellow method to update

```
like = Blog.objects.get(id=id)
for like in Likes.objects.filter(likes__some_bool_field =False): #or true by what you want to filter
    like.the_field_want_to_update.update(id=like.id)
```

here `.update` update the value by which you are filtering here with `id` so it will update what data passed to it.